# Can't access docker container in browser on redhat

Tags: docker, nginx, redhat

I am trying to run docker container on Redhat. What I did as:

- download nginx: `docker pull nginx`
- created html file at `home/username/index.html` and wrote "Welcome. I am Nginx server locked inside Docker"
- ran the command: `docker run --name my-nginx-c2 -p 8080:80 -v /home/username/html/:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro -d nginx`
- ran: `curl http://my-ip-address:8080` and can see the output "Welcome. I am Nginx server locked inside Docker"

now the problem is when I try to see it on browser that is `http://my-ip-address:8080`, it doesn't work.

Comment: I sometime have the same issue, chrome does not work but firebox can...

Comment: I have tried just now on firefox but same issue